# Gallery reset on screen rotate

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-gallery, baseadapter

i have a gallery view, with a BaseAdapter, and i download images from internet, download the image, and set to gallery async. There are about 2000 images.
When i rotate the screen, the asyntask continues, but the gallery set empty and dont show any now or old image.

This is the code of BaseAdapter:

```
private class AdaptadorImagenes extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context contexto = null;
        private ArrayList<Integer> datos = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        public AdaptadorImagenes(Context contexto) {

            this.contexto = contexto;
        }

        public void addItem(Integer posicion) {

            datos.add(posicion);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return datos.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ImageView imagen = new ImageView(contexto);
            imagen.setImageBitmap(getBitMapRedimensionado(position));
            imagen.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            return imagen;

        }

        /**
         * Metodo para redimensionar un bimap
         * 
         * @param posicion
         *            del bitmap en una lista que contiene los path
         * @return bitmap redimensionado
         */
        private Bitmap getBitMapRedimensionado(int posicion) {

            File fichero = new File(pathImagenes.get(posicion));
            Bitmap bmOriginal = redondeaEsquinasBitmap(Bitmap
                    .createScaledBitmap(
                            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fichero.toString()), 210,
                            210, true));

            return bmOriginal;
        }

        /**
         * Metodo para redondear las esquinas de un bitmap
         * 
         * @param bitmap
         *            a redondear
         * @return bitmap redondeado
         */
        public Bitmap redondeaEsquinasBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
            Bitmap salida = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                    bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);


Canvas canvas = new Canvas(salida);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = 12;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return salida;
    }

}
```

In the Manifiest i set             `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`

I think save in a variable how many images have downloaded yet and when rotate the screen set all the images, but when are more than 500 this process is very slow.

Any idea?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ImageLoader. This links can help [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012) or http://androidimageloader.com/

Also you can dismiss changing orientation in the AndroidManifest in activity:

```
android:name="com.example.MainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: I cant dissmis change orientation.
I will see your links. Thanks

Comment: I cant use this..Any other idea¿?